# Is there a better/faster way to do these multiple inserts using PHP and MariaDB?

Tags: php, optimization, mariadb

So I'm trying to build a small database to track high scores on the pinball machines in our league.  I have one table for users which is just an AI id column, and a column with their email address.  Then I have a games table which is an AI id column, and the names of the machines.  Since it is a many-to-many relationship, I made a third table called scores which has the user_id, game_id, and score as columns.

EDIT: Including read code:

```php
$file = fopen('scores.txt', 'r') or die("Unable to open file.");

// Loop through the file line by line
$line_number = 1;
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {

    // Reset flags
    $email_exists = 0;
    $game_exists = 0;
    if (isset($email_id)) unset($email_id);
    if (isset($game_id)) unset($game_id);
    echo ($line_number . " ");

    // Split the line into components
    $line = rtrim($line);
    $array = explode(",", $line, 3);
    $email = strtolower($array[0]);
    $game = $array[1];
    $score = $array[2];
    $stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT email_id FROM users WHERE email_address = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($email))
        if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email_address) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($email))
        $email_id = $db->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $email_id = $row['email_id'];
        $email_exists = 1;
    }
```

I use similar code to check if I already have a game listed in the database.  I need to get the id numbers for both the game and the email address for the third part which is seeing if the user already has a score for that game, and if the new score is higher if they already do.

```php
    if ($email_exists == 0 || $game_exists == 0) {
        // New user or game added to DB - no prior score can exist
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $stmt->execute(array($email_id,$game_id,$score));
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE email_id = ? AND game_id = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($email_id,$game_id));
        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
            // No previous score for this game
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?,?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($email_id,$game_id,$score));
        } else {
            // Previous score exists
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            if ($score > $row['score']) {
                // New score is higher
                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE scores SET score = ? " .
                    . "WHERE email_id = ? AND game_id =?");
                $stmt->execute(array($score, $email_id, $game_id));
                // No action needed if new score is lower
            }
        }
    }
```

The code seems to work fine, but it is slow.  Plus, it appears to make the script time out or something after a few thousand records.  Is there a better way to make this work?

I tried recoding it in Python but it was even slower and it appears it didn't even insert the rows in the database.  It probably doesn't help that I barely know Python.

I was thinking of creating an array and storing the items that need to be inserted, then inserting 100 rows at a time or something like that, but I need to get the id's for the scores junction table.  I also was considering using UNIQUE constraints in the database and am trying to figure out how to rewrite the insert code to use that to prevent duplicating email addresses or games.

Comment: How many records are we talking about here? If you're only going to insert the highest score, why bother inserting the ones you know you're going to just throw away? Process the CSV file first to find the highest value for each user/game, and then just insert that one record. Or insert multiples and then use max() or sort/limit later in your query find the highest.

Comment: Each week has about 8,000 records, I merged a few weeks together which worked but that's where I'm finding the limit at around 30k records.  I have data going back several years and once up-to-date, will continue (hopefully) to keep having 5-10k weekly records to process.

Comment: I'd just add a date field to the scores table and insert them all, then you've got nice historical data too. Also note if your query is the same for each loop iteration, you don't need to prepare it every time. Just prepare once (i.e., outside the loop) and then execute inside the loop.

Comment: What are you using to read and process the CSV file? If you are using PHP for that too please edit your question and include that code. The slow may be coming from someplace else.

Comment: I've added the code I use to process the CSV file. When you say "prepare outside the loop", how does that work when I change queries like 4-5 times?  I'll fully admit I don't fully grasp everything with PDO, but the execute() needs to know which statement to use right?

Comment: Thanks for the timestamp idea, that seems simple to implement and it would be great to have for historical data, instead of tossing lower scores.  I've only run the first batch and am shocked how slow it is and figured it was something I'm doing wrong since neither the db or the webserver are even sweating.  I should probably mention that the DB is hosted on a different physical host than the webserver, but they are connected through a 10GB link.

Comment: About your python code? I doubt that python is slower, since MariaDB Connector/Python's execute_many() method supports bulk operations (available since MariaDB server 10.2) which reduces network latency by sending the SQL statement with all data within one network packet.

Comment: @GeorgRichter yes, I'm sure the Python code not working is completely my fault.  I have done a number of DB projects in PHP so I am much more familiar with the language, whereas Python I've never used the MySQL modules.  It's extremely likely that I was not doing something correctly.  But the answer of using a stored procedure works really well for me in this case.  I've tweaked the code to prepare outside the loop (silly me, $stmt is just a named variable, use different ones for each query, duh!) and added timestamps so now the db has all the historical data, not just the highest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a stored procedure which has parameters email, game_id and score. Let the procedure do all SQL work for you. Your PHP code will be recuced to a sigle loop calling the proceudure. The result should be faster and far easier to maintain:

```
create procedure sp_add_email_score (
in_email varchar(320),
in_game_id int,
in_score int
)
begin

declare v_email_id int;

select email_id into v_email_id
from users 
where email_address = in_email;

if (v_email_id is null) then
  INSERT INTO users (email_address) VALUES (in_email);
  
  set v_email_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
end if;

INSERT INTO scores (email_id, game_id, score) 
VALUES(v_email_id, in_game_id, in_score) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score=if(in_score>score, in_score, score);;

end
```

If the loop is still too slow, then something else is causing the slowdown.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.  Didn't even think about just letting SQL do the work.

Comment: This will always overwrite a score, without regards to which is higher.

Comment: I added the timestamp idea from above and removed the duplicate key line.  No problems so far and triple the speed of my original code.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Added logic fior new score vs old one

Answer (score 0):

Lots of room for improvement here. When it comes to database speed, your primary goal should generally be reducing the number of hits to the database server.

First, you're doing the email-to-id query for every single CSV row, there's no need for that. At most, you should be doing it once per user and caching it. Better, you can do it once for the whole set, reading the whole thing into an in-memory array. Something like:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email_address, email_id FROM users');
$idMap = array_column($stmt->execute(), 'email_id', 'email_address');
```

This will give you an array like:

```
[
    'foo@bar.com' => 1,
    'baz@bar.com' => 2,
]
```

Do this once at the start of the script and keep it in memory for the duration. From this, you can instantly look up an id given an email. This removes 7999 hits to the database. You're essentially trading memory for CPU and disk time here. If you encounter an email that isn't yet in the array, you can INSERT it and add it to the array.

Next, move your prepares outside the loop iteration. This removes at least 3 * 7999 hits to the database and possibly as many as 5 * 7999 hits.

Next, use fgetcsv() instead of explode() because it's easier and will properly handle quoting. And process the whole CSV before doing a single insert. It's silly to create this enormous amount of database traffic if you're just going to throw away most of the records. So calculate the highest first, and then only hit the database with those:

```
$top = [];
$fp = fopen('scores.txt', 'r');
while ([$email, $gameId, $score] = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    if ($score > ($top[$email][$gameId] ?? 0)) {
        $top[$email][$gameId] = $score;
    }
}
```

Given an input file of:

```
foo@bar.com,g1,3
foo@bar.com,g1,1
foo@bar.com,g2,2
baz@bar.com,g1,4
baz@bar.com,g2,5
baz@bar.com,g2,6
```

This will yield an array of the highest scores for each user:

```
Array
(
    [foo@bar.com] => Array
        (
            [g1] => 3
            [g2] => 2
        )

    [baz@bar.com] => Array
        (
            [g1] => 4
            [g2] => 6
        )

)
```

Then, you can iterate over that array, and only perform inserts/updates based on those records. This will save two queries for every redundant CSV row.

```
foreach ($top as $email => $scores) {
    foreach ($scores as $gameId => $score) {
        // INSERT INTO scores ($idMap[$email], $gameId, $score)
    }
}
```